# How to remove data from view run-time?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I am developing MVC application and using razor syntax.

In this application I am giving comment facility.

I have added a partial view, which loads the comment/Records from DB.

In below image, we can see the comment box which is called run-time for employee index view.

problem is, when user delete comment, its get deleted from DB but how to remove it from the screen  without redirect to any page ?

I wan to remove that deleted comment div tag smoothly...

Please see the image...

[image]

my code is...

```
@model  IEnumerable<CRMEntities.Comment>

@{


     <div class="ParentBlock">


    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <div class="OwnerClass" id="OwnerName" data-comment-id="@item.Id">


         <span class="EmpName"> @Html.ActionLink(item.Owner.FullName, "Details", "EMployee", new { id = item.OwnerId }, new { @style = "color:#1A6690;" })</span>

           @Html.DisplayFor(ModelItem => item.CommentDateTime)

          <span class="EmpName"><button type="button" class="deleteComment">Delete</button></span>



        <p class="CommentP">
           @Html.DisplayFor(ModelItem => item.CommentText)
        </p>

        <br />
            <a class="Delete222" style="cursor:move;display:none;">DeleteNew</a>
        <br />

     </div>

    }


     <p class="p12">

      </p>



</div>

      <p id="ClassPara" class="ShowComments" onclick="chkToggle()">Show All Comments</p>

}


   @Html.TextArea("Comment", "", 5, 80, "asdsd")


    <input type="button" value="Add Comment" id="AddCommentButton"/>                         
    <input type="button" value="Clear" onclick="clearText()"/>                    

    <br />


</body>
</html>



<script src="../../Scripts/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".deleteComment").click(function () {
            alert("asd");
            var commentBlock = $(this).parent('.OwnerClass');
            commentBlock.hide('slow')

     });
    });


    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('.OwnerClass').hover(function () {
            $('.Delete222', this).show();
        }, function () {
            $('.Delete222').hide();


        });

    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of generating action link, place there button or . Bind JavaScript function to click event on this button, in this function make ajax call to action that deletes comment from db and use Jquery to hide proper div.

```
<span class="EmpName"><button type="button" class="deleteComment">Delete</button></span>
```

JavaScript:

```
$('.deleteComment').click(function () 

        {
            var commentBlock = $(this).parent('.ParentBlock');
            $.ajax({

                type: 'post',
                url: '/Comment/DeleteComment',
                dataType: 'json',
                data:
                { 

                 commentId: getCommentId(commentBlock )

                },
                success: function (data) {

                    commentBlock.hide('slow')

                }

            });
        });
```

**UPDATE:**

Update due to question update and comments below this answer:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".deleteComment").click(function () {

        var commentBlock = $(this).parent('.OwnerClass');

        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: '/Comment/DeleteComment',
            dataType: 'json',
            data:
            { 

             commentId: commentBlock.attr('data-comment-id')

            },
            success: function (data) {

                commentBlock.hide('slow')

            }

        });

 });
});
```

Comment: Thanks ebastian, This will work perfectly, but what should I write for      `commentId: getCommentId(commentBlock )` ?

Comment: You can add to .ParentBlock custom attribute data-comment-id, when you load comments set value of this attriute to comment id ($('.ParentBlock').attr('data-comment-id',123)), then in getCommentId(parentBlock) you simply return parentBlock.attr('data-comment-id').

Comment: In your code where you load comments after $(".ParentBlock").slideDown("slow"); put this: $('.ParentBlock').attr('data-comment-id',data.Id)

Comment: sorry , not getting what you want to say, one more in `DeleteComment` comment method I write following code...`[HttpPost]
        public JsonResult DeleteComment(int EId)
        {

            Comment comment = db.Comments.Find(EId);
            db.Comments.Remove(comment);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return Json(new { sc = true });
        }` is this correct ?

Comment: Thanks Sebastian, I am writing the code as per your instrucitons...but the query you are telling to update is used to add new comment. old comments didnt load from this query, I show comments using this code 
`@foreach (var item in Model)
    {
 <span class="EmpName"> @Html.ActionLink(item.Owner.FullName)</span>
 @Html.DisplayFor(ModelItem => item.CommentDateTime)
 @Html.DisplayFor(ModelItem => item.CommentText)
}` how to delete this comments ?

Comment: Ok, so put id not in ParentBlock but in owner: `@foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <div class="OwnerClass" id="OwnerName" data-comment-id="@item.Id">` ... then change code in click method from `var commentBlock = $(this).parent('.ParentBlock');` To `var commentBlock = $(this).parent('.OwnerClass');` Your implementation of DeleteCommon action seems ok.

Comment: `data-comment-id` is the invalid attribute ? How can we add own attribute in Div ?

Comment: `success: function (data) {

                    commentBlock.hide('slow')

                }` this code is not working...

Comment: Did you chnage selector for commentBlock ? Custom attributes which name starts with data- is a part of HTML5 standard.

Comment: Sebastian, Please check my updated code of my question...I will handle DB deleting part later...I just want to hide the div now...Please check Code now...hiding part is not right now...alert window come but it dont execute next part...

Comment: I've updated my answer, it should be ok, if it's not, you must debug your code. It's difficult to find bug without all code.